# Why do I get the Apple Mach-O Error in this simple code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have this pretty straightforward code, but somehow I get an Apple Mach-O error on this. Could anybody give me a clue to whats wrong?

**AvhorViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AvhorViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *WebViewAvhor;

@end
```

**AvhorViewController.m**

```
#import "AvhorViewController.h"

@interface AvhorViewController ()

@end

@implementation AvhorViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"one" ofType:@"htm" inDirectory:@"Avhor"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_WebViewAvhor loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

I have added the following frameworks:

```
AddressBookUI.framework
MapKit.framework
CoreLocation.framework
UIKit.framework
Foundation.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
```

**The meat of the error:**

> Ld
>   /Users/Centurion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Avhor-clfeavlkecrxomdmbtwixetebjsa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Avhor.app/Avhor
>   normal i386
>       cd /Users/Centurion/Documents/Xcode/Avhor
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/Centurion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Avhor-clfeavlkecrxomdmbtwixetebjsa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/Centurion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Avhor-clfeavlkecrxomdmbtwixetebjsa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist /Users/Centurion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Avhor-clfeavlkecrxomdmbtwixetebjsa/Build/Intermediates/Avhor.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Avhor.build/Objects-normal/i386/Avhor.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework AddressBookUI -framework MapKit -framework CoreLocation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/Centurion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Avhor-clfeavlkecrxomdmbtwixetebjsa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Avhor.app/Avhor
>
> ld: can't open output file for writing:
>   /Users/Centurion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Avhor-clfeavlkecrxomdmbtwixetebjsa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Avhor.app/Avhor,
>   errno=21 for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Can you post the meat of the error, not just Mach-O?

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/119869/ios) for the same problem. What you can try (usual Xcode steps to solve the problems):

- manually delete the file in error message
- clean project
- reopen Xcode

Comment: I googeled a bit before I posted this, so I have tried those steps. But Ill read a bit on that link to see if it can help me, thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

The error was because I had named the folder where I kept the local content the same as the name of the project.

I did the following:

- Deleted folder with local content (in Finder
- Cleaned project
- Added the files in a folder with a different name

Comment: So the question *was* a duplicate.  Why did you accept the incorrect answer?